# Can't query tag and post_type at the same time

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, tags

On my developer site this query is used for a carousel in index.php :

```
$vedette_accueil = new WP_Query(array(
                     'tag' => 'vedette-accueil',
                     'nopaging' => true,
                     'post_type' => array('post','mensuels')
                  ));
```

`mensuels` is a simple custom post type with post abilities and uses the `post_tag` taxonomy. it is used to present a few articles of particular interest - described in a paragraph - for a given month. 
It works as intended. It shows up in the carousel as intended.

On the *production* server, my cpt does not show up in the carousel. Every thing else about it works just fine: its pages work, it's there in the tab assigned to it in the index page, but just won't show up in the carousel. I even do a `wp_reset_postdata()` between queries.

The only difference between implementations is that I named it `themes_mensuels` rather than `mensuels`. that's it. I pick the tag from the list, I can see it stick to my cpt because I have proper results in admin:

> [mysite.ca]/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=themes_mensuels&tag=vedette-accueil

Here are the first few lines of `var_dumps` of the query. First, DEV (that works):

```
 object(WP_Query)#11489 (49) {
  ["query"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["tag"]=>
    string(15) "vedette-accueil"
    ["nopaging"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["post_type"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "post"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "mensuels"
    }
  }
  ["query_vars"]=>
  array(64) {
    ["tag"]=>
    string(15) "vedette-accueil"
    ["nopaging"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["post_type"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "post"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "mensuels"
    }
```

Here is PROD:

```
    object(WP_Query)#10593 (49) {
  ["query"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["tag"]=>
    string(15) "vedette-accueil"
    ["nopaging"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["post_type"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(15) "themes_mensuels"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "post"
    }
  }
  ["query_vars"]=>
  array(64) {
    ["tag"]=>
    string(15) "vedette-accueil"
    ["nopaging"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["post_type"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "post"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "page"
    }
```

The funny thing is that i can query "just" the post type and see the few I have in the carousel. But when I add the tag, it just bumps the cpt.

I did a bit of research and the naming seems conventional. I added the recommendation from [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types_in_the_Main_Query).

but to no avail.

What very subtle WP idiosyncrasy am I missing??

Comment: Can you spot something in debug.log?

Comment: Now is the right time to learn how to use it. Will get back with info

Comment: Is this supposed to do anything:  define( 'SAVEQUERIES', true ); cause I have unrelated errors so far.

Comment: I will rename my CPT to be the same as in DEV. If that helps, I will be disappoint in WP for such a silly fault

Comment: well, it was a lot of messing about, and the cpt is now named "mensuels" just like it is in dev, Everything works as expected EXCEPT it STILL won't appear in the carousel. I furthered my research by closely comparing the var_dumps of both DEV and Prod. Apart from the result, no other differences show up.

Comment: No other _new_ differences show up

Comment: how do i reverse-engeneering this "feature". If I WANTED to exclude a custom post type, how would I go about it ? there are just a couple fillters used for this simple site, having to do with the comment count and the pubdate, but right now, my test page just makes the query and dumps it, no presenting of data, nothing.

Comment: oh wait. I went ahead and phpinfo() both sites. and SOMEONE didn't upgrade the dev to php 7.2.

Comment: Still, my query is stupid simple. How can it not work ?

Comment: What the hell. ` 'tag_slug__in'=>array( 'vedette-accueil'), `. Now it works.

Comment: Note the codex about registering post types: "Post type. (max. 20 characters, cannot contain capital letters, underscores or spaces)". See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type. It's odd because some reserved post types violate this. My guess it's hard to predict whether you'll run up against this restriction or not.

Comment: That is a confusing rule, considering I _can_ query for just the post_type elsewhere in the page. Still, once I switched it to just "mensuels" that rule no longer show have caused problems. so what did ? There IS a php version difference between the two servers, but I don't remember seeing anything about my problem. Also, I have been _negotiating_ with the bosses a proper development freeze time to upgrade to WP 5.1.*

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using

```
'tag_slug__in'=>array( 'vedette-accueil'),
```

and now it works. How this is different from

```
'tag' => 'vedette-accueil',
```

and how the later would transform the query so that the cpt was ignored, I may never know...but I would love it if someone told me.